# Rectangle OOP/classes

Tags: python

I need to make a rectangle data class and an executable program to test it.

[image]

This is the full problem that I am dealing with:

In the executable's main function:

- prompt the user to enter the length and width of a rectangle.
- create a new Rectangle instance with the dimensions entered by the
  user.
- to verify the above step, print both dimensions using their
  respective "getter" methods.
- test the area() method by printing the rectangle area, accurate to two
  decimal places.
- test the perimeter() method by printing the rectangle perimeter,
  accurate to two decimal places.
- change the length to 22.345 and change the width to 15.789.
- test the area() and perimeter() methods again. You should get the
  results shown in the sample output.*

My question is, **does the class file have to be in the same folder as the executable file?**

If anyone wants to provide tips on the rest of it, please do.  This is what I have for the rectangle class:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.__length = length
        self.__width = width

    def set_length(self, length):
        self.__length = length 

    def set_width(self, model):
        self.__width = width 

    def get_length(self):
        return self.__length 

    def get_width(self):
        return self.__width

    def get_area(self):
        return self.__getwidth() * self.getlength()

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return self.__getwidth() * 2 + getlength() * 2
```

Comment: yes both files should be in the same location... your class looks fine ...

Comment: In some places you used `get_width` and others `getlength`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks for that. Now to try and make sense of the rest of this somehow...missed the lecture on this stuff, feel free to comment. Thanks again!

Comment: @BradleyGaragan nope! I was following a book trying to make sense of this, and must have wrote it wrong on accident. Thanks! Unless that makes sense that way as well? Or does it need to be all the same?

Comment: Your class and the main script do NOT have to be in the same file or in the same folder.  The Python import mechanism is designed to handle that.  Python is not Java.  Each class does not have to be in a separate file, and you can name the files any way you want.  Also your class contains many typos and inconsistent variable names; `__getwidth` is not the same as `get_width` and `getlength` is not the same as `get_length`.

Comment: Getters and setters? You're not using [Introduction to Programming Using Python](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Programming-Using-Python-Daniel/dp/0132747189/) for your textbook by any chance, are you?

Comment: Nope using: http://www.amazon.com/Starting-Out-Python-Tony-Gaddis/dp/0133582736/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1432081143&sr=1-1&keywords=starting+out+with+python

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 and the question its asking is not very well explained...having trouble trying to solve the rest of this question...

Comment: "Tony Gaddis is the principal author of the Starting Out With series of textbooks... The Starting Out With series includes introductory books covering C++, Java™...". I guess I shouldn't be surprised that there's more than one Python book written by someone who thinks in Java. Sell that book to someone you don't like, and learn Python from the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: Hell. for me at least. But Its from a class I am taking in person, and I missed the past 2 weeks due to family matters, so I am completely lost and have until the end of this week to get caught up.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks for that. I feel like I am kind of screwed in general for this assingment

Comment: With this kind of book, you will slowly learn how to unprogram in Python. =\

Comment: Well.. that is great to know..lol, thankfully my program is not focused on programming and more on hardware/troubleshooting...just need to pass this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 If a "good programmer" is one who can write a Fortran program in any language, what do you call one who can write a Java program in any language? :-)

Comment: @Paul, you call them something in Perl (e.g. `%$!&*@$!`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few corrections to typos, you can put the class definition right inside your main program:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, length, width): # this initializes the object with the given parameters
        self.__length = length # assign length
        self.__width = width # assign width

    def set_length(self, length): # this method allows us pass the Rectangle object a value and set the object's length to the given value
        self.__length = length # assign length

    def set_width(self, width): # had 'model' here # same thing, for width
        self.__width = width # assign width

    def get_length(self): # this method does one thing...
        return self.__length # return the Rectangle object's length

    def get_width(self): # and same for width
        return self.__width

    def get_area(self): # this actually does something: multiplies width by height and returns that value
        return self.get_width() * self.get_length() # underscores were wrong

    def get_perimeter(self): # similarly, this adds double the length to double the width and returns that value
        return self.get_width() * 2 + self.get_length() * 2 # underscores were wrong, missing self

def main(): # our main program, which will test our Rectangle class
    length = float(input('Length? ')) # request a length and turn that string into a float
    width = float(input('Width? ')) # request a width and turn that string into a float
    rectangle = Rectangle(length, width) # create a new Rectangle object with the given length and width
    print(rectangle.get_length(), rectangle.get_width()) # print the object's length and width, using the getters
    print(round(rectangle.get_area(), 2)) # round the area to 2 places and print it
    print(round(rectangle.get_perimeter(), 2)) # round the perimeter to 2 places and print it
    rectangle.set_length(22.345) # calls the Rectangle object's length setter and passes it a new value, which will set the object's length to the given value
    rectangle.set_width(15.789) # same for width
    print(round(rectangle.get_area(), 2)) # print the area again to see the new value
    print(round(rectangle.get_perimeter(), 2)) # print the perimeter again to see the new value

main() # call our main method - without this, nothing happens
```

NB: Getters and setters do not belong in a Python program. A proper Python `Rectangle` would look like this:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length # no need to mask these by starting the names with _
        self.width = width

    @property # this lets us call this method without parentheses - it'll look like an ordinary attribute, but it's really calling a method
    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*(self.length + self.width) # the original has 2 multiplications and 1 addition, while this has 1 multiplication and 1 addition - negligible, but it's good to see this sort of thing once in a while in case you have to optimize something at some point
```

That would be used as such:

```
>>> a = Rectangle(3.2,5.1)
>>> a.area
16.32
>>> a.perimeter
16.6
>>> a.length=2
>>> a.area
10.2
>>> a.perimeter
14.2
>>> a.length
2
```

But look out:

```
>>> a.area = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

That makes as much sense as, say, `rectangle.get_area() = 3` - i.e., none.

Comment: Thanks for this! Going to go through it and try to understand it by recreating similar things.... What exactly are the getters and setters in what you posted anyway?

Comment: A "getter" method retrieves the value of a given (private) variable and returns it to the outside world. A "setter" method takes in a value from the outside world and assigns it to the given (private) variable. In Python, however, these are useless, as you can access the variables directly with, e.g., `print(rectangle.__length)` or `rectangle.width = 4.5`. There's no such thing as a truly private variable in Python.

Comment: Okay gotcha. Its working for me, but when I try and enter a number with a decimal like 12.45 for example, I get an error.

Comment: Yeah was just going to try that. I need to research more on float/int to understand the complete difference.

Comment: if you have any time and are open to it, could you provide some comments in the code for me to fully understand everything? Trying to take it step by step in my mind and would help. Thanks, and no worries if not.

Comment: Sure; I'll add more comments later tonight.

Comment: I've added a bunch of comments and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Your class looks more or less fine. However, in the first picture you posted describing the class setup, it appears that `get_area()` and `get_perimeter()` should be named simply `area()` and `perimeter()`. There are some other minor typos as @PaulCornelius mentioned that will result in errors.

Your "executable file", i.e. the file that calls the methods of your `Rectangle` class can be in another file, but **it doesn't need to be**. For example:

```
class Rectangle:
    #all of the above stuff
r= Rectangle(10,20)
print r.get_area()
```

will work just fine, printing the area of the rectangle.

Otherwise you can create a new file that includes `import rectangle` to import your `Rectangle` class. This does require it to be in the same folder (or you must configure Python so it knows where to look for the module).

Creating the script that actually calls your methods is the best way to verify things behave properly, and may provide hints as to how to fix them. For example, trying to call `get_area()` on a `Rectangle` will result in an error (as `__getwidth()` is not defined anywhere, but `get_width()` is).

Comment: also, for the perimiter and area, should I keep the (self) in parenthesis after each or remove that as well?

Comment: Because these are `class` functions (i.e. methods), you need to keep the `(self)` portion. I like to think of this as the object inputting itself into the function, since the function acts on it. Hope that makes sense.